# bootstrap row four blocks

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to align them centered, I use bootstrap

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-4"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Centered how...please clarify?

Comment: I also think your `xs` size should be 12...right? - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/qObezd

Comment: What's the problem? Bootstrap container is centered by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class center as follows.

```
.center {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `container` instead of `container-fluid`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply suggest you to use **bootstrap** itself.

Just use:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://DEMO)